# If I am rendering with blender, can I open a new project while it is rendering?

Tags: rendering

If I am rendering with blender, can I open a new project while it is rendering?

I will show you what I do when I try to open another page...

Ok, so while my project is rendering, I open up the Blender icon[image]

This opens up a new page[image]

I save this project[image][image]

Then I open up the document(while my other project is rendering)

[image]

Then this pops up
[image]

I always thought that if I rendered something huge that would take weeks to render, couldn't I also be working with Blender on another project?
I know this a lot but it would really help me if someone figured it out...

Comment: If you want to do both, I suggest opening a new instance of Blender instead so one will render and you can work on the other

Comment: Instance? What is an instance?

Comment: Each time you run a program, you create an instance of that program. To open another instance (also known as windows) just open Blender again as you normally would while keeping the other one open.

Comment: I can open and work on another page, but when I save it and open it again, it says,"You can't open the application "blender" because it may be damaged or incomplete.

Comment: @BlenderWonder Can you edit your post and list the exact steps you are currently taking? Screenshots would help as well as the current version of Blender and operating system you are using. When asking be as detailed as possible so you can possibly get more interest and possibly answers to those who see your question for the first time.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87/is-it-possible-to-work-on-two-or-more-files-at-the-same-time-or-open-multiple-b/96#96

Comment: It would be, except I can't open the page. So its a different problem...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just open a new instance of Blender:

**Windows:**
Right click on the blender icon then choose Blender. This will open new blender instance.

**Linux:**
Just run the application another time

**Mac OS:**
By default, only 1 instance of an app can be run. You can work around this limitation by invoking Blender from the terminal command line. `open -n /Applications/blender.app`

Comment: Can you break down what that means(Mac OS)?

Comment: So you opened a blender instance, run the rendering, keep this blender opened. Then open terminal in your Mac then copy this command `open -n /Applications/blender.app` and paste it in your terminal and run it, it should open another instance of blender while keeping the other instance opened.

Comment: I did what you said but it then said-The file /Applications/blender.app does not exist...

Comment: @BlenderWonder yes because I don't know where you are placing the blender folder. you can use this `open -n /place your blender directory here/blender.app`

Comment: It still says files do not exist, if I find my blender folder and use terminal with open -n /Applications/blender.app, will it work?

Comment: @BlenderWonder Could you open the folder where blender is located and then right click on the blender app icon then get info and send me a screenshot of that?

Comment: I can't open a picture in the comments.

Comment: you can use pasteall.org but now it's getting more complicated a video will be better to show what exactly you do

Comment: We should discuss on chat, but I need more reputation.

Comment: @BlenderWonder Please accept the answer to this question and open another question showing the other problem with steps and screenshots and send me the link of the new question here and I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I once tried to do it myself and i find that when you open a new blend file during render it takes time for the blend file to really open(When I started it was slow and after a while it worked fine), but if u give it some time, 5 minutes perhaps depending on your computer, it will open completely and then it should work.